# Is it a VGA issue when millions of randomly colored pixels shown on my two LCD monitors when switching them on?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, lcd

I have just purchased a new Video card Asrock Phantom Rx 570 4GB. I attached one of my LCD monitor to the card via the DVI port. Every time I turn the monitor on there are an animated millions of randomly colored pixels shown as follows. If I toggle the monitor on and off several times, the monitor works normal (it shows the proper contents that I want to show). Sometimes, this phenomenon also appears when  I am using the computer rather than when switching the monitor on.

I thought the problem is related to the monitor but if I change to another monitor, the same issue still appears. Both monitors are LCD and  relatively old version (2008-2013 products).

Is it due to the VGA that is too superior?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Asrock Phantom Rx is defective. You should return and/or replace it. By your own testing, the monitors are not the source of the problem. Since it occurs at power up, before the operating system loads, it's not a driver issue.

Comment: Sorry. The phenomenon occurs after entering Windows rather than booting session.

Comment: If a new driver or updated firmware from the manufacturer is available, try them.  If that doesnt fix the issue, it is defective

Comment: OK. THanks. I will try it. :-)